# What are the verses that accept the authority of the Vedas in Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Samkhya and Yoga Sutras?

Tags: yoga, sankhya, shad-darshana, nyaya, vaisheshika

Out of six orthodox Hindu Philosophical schools, Vedanta and Mimamsa directly philosophize the Gyanakanda and Karmakanda of the Vedas.

The other four schools (Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Samkhya and Yoga) have their own philosophical ideas. However, they accept the authority of the Vedas (that is why these are in the fold of Hinduism).

There must be some verses in their respective Sutras that declare it explicitly. I want to know these verses. Please quote directly from the Sutras or their commentaries but not from other secondary sources.

Answer (score 3):

In **Vaisheshika-sutra 1.1.3 and 10:2:9**, Vedas are referred as word of God.

> तद्वचनादाम्नायस्य प्रामाण्यम् ॥

> The authoritativeness of the Veda (arises from its) being the Word of God [or being an exposition of dharma].

Vedas are a work of intelligence.

> बुद्धिपूर्वा वाक्यकृतिर्वेदे ॥ ६.१.१ ॥

> In the Veda the composition of sentence has been preceded by understanding.